# Get task from a string for a todolist project

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to return the task to do (for a todolist project) with a function that takes as parameter some strings...
In fact, Iam trying to program this https://github.com/todotxt/todo.txt in python 3

So basically I have a dict that I have to fill with: •The priority (from A highest priority to Z lowest priority)

• 'x' whether the task has been done or not yet

• find and fill the completion and creation date (YYYY-MM-DD)

• find the context which starts with a '@' and update the dict

• find the project which starts with a '+' and update dict..

• N order of the task in the file..(will see later)

• finally strings that are none of these are the task, so I update the dict with this task and return it...

Here's my Python code so far:

```
def parser_task(line):

    """
    :param:(str) a line
    :return: (dict) dict representing the task to do
    :Contraints: None?

    Examples:

    >>> parser_task('x (A) 2018-03-02 2018-03-04 do you homeworks +studies @home')
    {'text': 'do your homeworks'}
    >>> parser_task('Call mom (A) @ phone @sededay')
    {'text': 'Call mom'}
    >>> parser_task('X 2019-01-01 wish happy new year to everyone')
    {'text': 'wish happy new year to everyone'}

    """
    dict = { 
                'N': '',
                'X':'',
                'completionDate':'',
                'creationDate':'',
                'priority':'',
                'context':'',
                'project':'',
                'text':''
            }
    liste_prioritie = [chr(k) for k in range(ord("A"),ord("Z"))]

    ligne_decouped = ligne.split(' ')

    for i in range(len(ligne_decouped)):
        if '(' in ligne_decouped[i]:
            a = ligne_decouped[i]
            for char in ligne_decouped[i]:
                if char == "(":
                     a = a.replace(char,"")
                if char == ")":
                     a = a.replace(char,"")
            dict['priority'] = a
            del ligne_decouped[i]
        if 'x' == ligne_decouped[i]:
            dict['X'] = ligne_decouped[i]
            del ligne_decouped[i]
        if '-' in ligne_decouped[i]:
            dict['creationnDate'] = ligne_decouped[i]
            del ligne_decouped[i]
        if '-' in ligne_decouped[i]:
            dict['completionDate'] = ligne_decouped[i]
            del ligne_decouped[i]
        if '+' in ligne_decouped[i]:
            dict['project'] = ligne_decouped[i]
            del ligne_decouped[i]
        if '@' in ligne_decouped[i]:
            dict['context'] = ligne_decouped[i]
            del ligne_decouped[i]
    return ligne_decouped
```

I keep getting list index out of range in `if '(' in line_decouped[i]:`

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Are you sure all of your variable names are correct? I am having a difficult time locating where you assign your variables. For instance, what is `ligne_decouped`. And why are you looping over `char` in `ligne_decouped[i]` when you never seem to use `char`?

Comment: I don't see any `if '(' in line_splitted[i]:`and you create `liine_splitted` with 2 i

Comment: Ah yes thanks I'll fix this because my code had variables in french so I translated it and had typos

Comment: Please do, because it's virtually unreadable at this point.

Comment: I'll keep their original names. ligne_decouped is the parameter line that has been splitted according to the space " ". also for the char loop I missed two ifs

Comment: I would just use `regex` to accomplish what you want. You are deleting words from a split string, therefore you are deleting words from a list as you iterate through it, which will lead to a whole slew of problems...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what regex is. I'm currently at my  first year at college and we didn't see anything like that only basic python to python with files and stuff.. I can't use something I have not seen yet if you see what I mean

Comment: `regex` corresponds to regular expressions, which are an efficient way to identify patterns in text and extract those groups, exactly what you are aiming to do here. I would spend an hour, if that, to learn the very basics of `regex`, it will pay serious dividends in terms of text parsing and string manipulation.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend `regex` for this task (BTW, still unsure what you intend to assign to `N` in your dictionary). The following will work for the example that you provided, however without multiple examples this is not guaranteed to work for all of your cases:

```
import re

def parser_task(ligne):

    ligne_decouped = { 
                'N': '',
                'X':'',
                'completionDate':'',
                'creationDate':'',
                'priority':'',
                'context':'',
                'project':'',
                'text':''
            }

    dates = re.findall(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}', ligne)
    ligne_decouped['creationDate'] = dates[0]
    ligne_decouped['completionDate'] = dates[1]
    ligne_decouped['priority'] = re.search(r'\(([A-Z])\)', ligne).group(1)
    ligne_decouped['context'] = re.search(r'(?<=@)(.*)$', ligne).group(1)
    ligne_decouped['X'] = re.search(r'^(.)', ligne).group(1)
    ligne_decouped['project'] = re.search(r'(?<=\+)(\S+)', ligne).group(1)
    ligne_decouped['text'] = re.search(dates[1] + r'\s+(.*?)\s+\+', ligne).group(1)
    return ligne_decouped

print(parser_task('x (A) 2018-03-02 2018-03-04 do you homeworks +studies @home'))
```

Yields:

```
{
'N': '',
'X': 'x',
'completionDate': '2018-03-04',
'creationDate': '2018-03-02',
'priority': 'A',
'context': 'home',
'project': 'studies',
'text': 'do you homeworks'
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right, this doesn't work on any 'kind' of line for instance if my parameter is '(A) Call Mom' it return list index out of range.. Still thank you for time and help I was still trying to understand regex

Comment: *Because anything besides the task itself doesn't have to be specified for the program to run correctly

Comment: You could wrap the `regex` searches inside of try-except blocks if some of the information is not always provided, however like I said, very difficult to write a generalized code with a single example. If this answered your original question, feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: I added some examples if you still want to look at it, but now I have an idea of what to do to deal with the missing information with the try/except blocks. Again thank you for your help this far.